# jq - how to create an output including double quote surrouding field values

Tags: json, jq

## Background

The command below produce a JSON stream.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stack} --region us-east-1 |\
jq --arg STACK ${stack} '.Stacks[] | select(.StackName=="mlai-metadata-development-backend") | .Outputs[] | select(.ExportName != null)
```

```
{
  "OutputKey": "outputvpcid",
  "OutputValue": "vpc-d4520cb1",
  "Description": "VPC ID of the Stack mlai-metadata-development-backend",
  "ExportName": "stack-vpc-id"
}
{
  "OutputKey": "outputvpccidr",
  "OutputValue": "172.31.0.0/16",
  "Description": "VPC CIDR of the Stack mlai-metadata-development-backend",
  "ExportName": "stack-vpc-cidr"
}
```

I like to create a JSON dictionary like `{"stack-vpc-cidr": "172.31.0.0/16"}`.

Running this:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stack} --region us-east-1 |\
jq --arg STACK ${stack} '.Stacks[] | select(.StackName=="mlai-metadata-development-backend") | .Outputs[] | select(.ExportName != null) | "\(.ExportName):\(.OutputValue)"'
```

creates.

```
"stack-vpc-id:vpc-d4520cb1"
"stack-vpc-cidr:172.31.0.0/16"
```

### Question

How can I turn them into lines of JSON dictionary using jq?

---

## Update

Thanks to the answers, got it right.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${stack} --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} |\
jq --arg stack ${stack} \
  '[.Stacks[] | select(.StackName==$stack) | .Outputs[] |
  select(.ExportName != null) | { (.ExportName) : (.OutputValue) }] |
  add' |\
tee "${stack}".json
```

Result:

```
{
  "apigw-rest-api-conntent-metadata-url": "https://****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/development/",
  "apigw-rest-api-conntent-metadata-stage-name": "development",
  "stack-availability-zones": "us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c,us-east-1d,us-east-1e,us-east-1f",
  "apigw-rest-api-conntent-metadata-deployment-id": "***0tk",
  "stack-vpc-id": "vpc-d4520cb1",
  "stack-vpc-cidr": "172.31.0.0/16"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I [would] like to create a JSON dictionary

To create a single dictionary from the stream:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i (null;
  . + ($i|{ (.ExportName) : (.OutputValue) }))'
```

Or you could modify your jq invocation to use a similar snippet along the lines of:

```
[ .Stacks[] .... 
 | { (.ExportName) : (.OutputValue) } ]
| add
```

Answer (score 3):

For your immediate problem at the last hop, you can just do below which does [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-(foo), in `jq`

```
{ "\(.ExportName)" : "\(.OutputValue)" }
```

but you can just do below by spelling out the explicit k/v names

```
{ (.ExportName) : (.OutputValue) }
```